# Is unordered_set<reference_wrapper<Ty>> valid?

Tags: c++, reference, c++11, hashset

Is this valid C++ (considering the latest standard)? I'm getting compilation errors with near-top-of-tree clang/libc++ on Ubuntu 12.04. If it should be valid, I'll mail the clang-dev list with error messages and such.

```
#include <functional>
#include <unordered_set>

struct X
{
    int i; 
};

void f ()
{
    std::unordered_set<std::reference_wrapper<X>> setOfReferencesToX;

    // Do stuff with setOfReferencesToX
}
```

** As an aside, I'm tired of qualifying that the question/answer is specific to the latest standard.  Could the C++ community as a whole, please start qualifying things that are specific to the old standard instead?  The newer standard has been out for about a year now.

Comment: "Could the C++ community as a whole, please start qualifying things that are specific to the old standard instead?" No. Given the sheer number of users who are not able to upgrade to a compiler with more complete C++11 support, let alone the popularity of a certain compiler family that is only slowly upgrading it's C++11 support, C++ is going to mean C++03 for at least another year if not two. And lets not forget that neither GCC nor Clang claims full conformance to C++11. The future is not the present, and pretending that it is will not make it so.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not specific to `std::reference_wrapper<T>`, but rather to the type `X` itself.

The issue is that [std::unordered_set](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) requires that you define hashing and equality functors for `std::reference_wrapper<X>`. You can pass the hash functor as second template parameter.

For example, this would work:

```
#include <functional> // for std::hash<int>

struct HashX {
  size_t operator()(const X& x) const {
    return std::hash<int>()(x.i);      
  }
};
```

and then

```
std::unordered_set<std::reference_wrapper<X>, HashX> setOfReferencesToX;
```

Another option is to make a specialization for `std::hash<X>`:

```
namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<X> {
  size_t operator()(const X& x) const {
    return std::hash<int>()(x.i);      
  }
};
}
```

This allows you to avoid explicitly specifying the 2nd template argument:

```
std::unordered_set<std::reference_wrapper<X>> setOfReferencesToX;
```

Concerning the equality comparison, you can fix this by providing an equality operator for class `X`:

```
struct X
{
  bool operator==(const X& rhs) const { return i == rhs.i; }
  int i; 
};
```

Otherwise, you can define your own functor and pass it as third template argument.

Comment: Wouldn't specializing `std::hash` be a bit simpler?

Comment: It would, if you are willing to put stuff in the `std` namespace.

Comment: I don't think it should be qualified as "putting stuff in `std`", as it's mere specialization...

Comment: @Griwes OK, I added an example doing just that. It is what I normally do, but I am not sure whether it is frowned upon or not :-)

Comment: Your last example does need to use `std::hash<X>` explicitly as the hasher, otherwise it will defer to `std::hash<std::reference_wrapper<X>>`.

Comment: Luc is right. I was just testing your solution and you still need to do `std::unordered_set<std::reference_wrapper<X>, std::hash<X>> setOfReferencesToX;`, otherwise it won't work. I am not sure how to avoid this second template parameter on a reference_wrapper-keyed hash container.